# Extract zone offset from a moment's date

Tags: momentjs, timezone-offset

I need to build a function that receives a string with a date and I need to extract the time offset.

```
var moment = require('moment');
function extractZoneOffset(date){
  ...
}

extractZoneOffset("2015-12-11 00:00:00-03:00") // -3
extractZoneOffset("2015-12-11 00:00:00-04:00") // -4
extractZoneOffset("2015-12-11 00:00:00Z") // 0
extractZoneOffset("2015-12-11 00:00:00-05:00") // -5
```

I can't find a function to extract the timezone neither in [moment's docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) nor in [moment-timezone's docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: How about `moment(date).utcOffset(date).format("ZZ")`?

Comment: I thought about that solution, but it is not an "elegant" one. For example, `moment("2015-12-11T00:00:00-03:00").utcOffset("2015-12-11T00:00:00-03:00").format('ZZ')` will return `"-0300"`, I can slice the last 2 characters and parseInt the result, but I think moment should have something better to do this.